# What is this thing called

Tags: identification, components

I used to use this thing to setup variable load to my AC output.
It is a smoothly variable resistor, Just slide, and resistance vary smoothly unlike Decade Resistors.. But I cannot remember the exact name.
In our lab we just call it "slideck" (sic). But, i need the actual name
because I want to buy one. Does anybody know where I can get one of these?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a

- [rheostat](http://www.resistorguide.com/rheostat/)

or

- [potentiometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potentiometer)

but you can also just call it a variable resistor.

What term is more commonly used depends on the country you're in and/or what is common in certain fields of electronics. In low power electronics we tend to use potentiometer or potmeter. In power electronics Rheostat is more common. Your's is a more of a high-power device to I'd call it a rheostat.

Answer (score 2):

It's a potentiometer or rheostat. You can buy them e.g. here [culatti.ch](http://www.culatti.ch/language/en/home-en/)